# $window.innerHeight returns different values in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to determine the viewport height with `$window.innerHeight` or `document.documentElement.clientHeight` but it turns out that Firefox and Chrome are returning different values (a few pixels).

Anyone already faced this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The height of the body is determined by the available height inside the browser window.

Different browsers have different graphic interfaces, varying toolbar heights, number of toolbars, etc. All those elements will influence the height available for the actual HTML content.

Try the following in various browsers (in full size)

```js
console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

The height you are getting is more that likely because the design of firefox and chrome are different by a few pixels. I can resize my browser to however I want. Monitor and resolution also determines that. Not really an issue if you are designing your UI correctly, meaning using media queries in CSS and creating a responsive design instead of fixed values.